# Currently focused field is deprecated and will be removed in a future release

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I have a next problem: first, my Android studio crashed and I couldn't run my application, then a probelm with jetifier occured and then I have an error "currently focused field is deprecated and will be removed in a future release". Interesting fact: I haven't seen this error before. It started, after Android Studio had crashed. My code is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, TextInput, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { SIGN_IN } from '../routes'
import { MyButton, MyTextInput, Header } from '../uikit'
import { w, h, styles } from '../constants/constants'

export default class LogIn extends Component {
    state = {

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Header title={'Welcome!'.toUpperCase()} />
                <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
                    <MyTextInput
                        placeholder={'Email/Login'}
                        isSecure={false}
                    />
                    <MyTextInput
                        placeholder={'Password'}
                        isSecure={true}
                    />
                    <View style={styles.buttons}>
                        <MyButton
                            name={'Log in'.toUpperCase()}
                            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(SIGN_IN)} />
                        <MyButton
                            name={'Sign in'.toUpperCase()}
                            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(SIGN_IN)} />
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was simple. I had just updated my router-navigator to newest version